# Bootstrap 3: simple vertical align 2 divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to give automatically the same height for #div1 and #div2 whatever my logo size is. Is there a specific Bootstrap3 class to do the job ? If not which is the best css rules to apply ?

https://jsfiddle.net/bzq9bhop/4/

```
<div class="masthead">
    <!-- Logo + Titre du site -->
    <div class="row">
        <div id="div1" class="col-xs-6" style="border:solid 1px;"><img src="http://drawception.com/pub/panels/2012/12-28/MnbfrYALQj-2.png" width="250" height="150" /></div>
        <div id="div2" class="col-xs-6" style="border:solid 1px;"><h1>My website title</h1></div>
    </div>
```

Edit: Finally I used this solution. http://www.bootply.com/wr4u8YOFpj

Simple and elegant with only 1 bootstrap class list-inline

Which in my code gives:

```
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><img src="//placehold.it/150x50"></li>
                    <li><h1>My text</h1></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add display:flex; to the style of the parent div that you want to have same height..flexbox will take care of the rest..

Comment: Nice to see you again sir. Your answer is the good one. The stackoverflow's system is telling me I must wait 8minutes to be able to accept your answer ... so in 8 minutes I will accept it ... Thanky you !

Comment: you're welcome..I really needed a lot of help when i got started and felt really happy when somebody took the time to help me so I feel obliged to help others ( whenever i can ) who need some assistance..take care and god bless

Comment: Can I center the content of my div with a flex property ? I need content of my div is centered

Comment: yes..use justify-content: center; in the parent div .. just an advise..take some time and learn flexbox..it will probably take a couple of hours to learn it but you will save hundreds of hours in coding..

Comment: Yes I will learn felxbox because actualy css is a kind of little nightmare to me. Sorry but justify-content: center; does not work. What I would exactly need is content of #div1 and content of #div2 having bottom align. Like any header of every website.

Comment: i am assuming you meant contents sticking to the baseline of the div and in that case you can do align-items: baseline;

Comment: That's a good answer. But my <h1> tag is too big. So it's hard to have a content align beetween my logo and the <h1> tag. I need to look for my solution Thank you for having helped me sir ! ;-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bzq9bhop/12/ maybe you could look at this jsfiddle ? there are not many lines of code. I would content of both div are aligned

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: flex` to the parent container. Check update [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bzq9bhop/5/).

Change `<div class="row">` to `<div class="row" style="display: flex">`